# Best practices for storing passwords for PHP and MySQL applications

Tags: passwords, hash, php, mysql, bcrypt

I am creating a simplified lead and call management system for a friend's small business.

I would like to know the best practices for hardening password storage and verification using PHP 7.4 and MySQL 7.4.30.

I would like something very secure as some of the data I am storing is subject to HIPPA rules for data storage.

The password hash function creates hashes based on the old bcrypt standards which can be easily broken when one has adequate CPU/GPU resources.

Therefore, I need more robust solutions.

Comment: In general, passwords used for authenticating users should not be stored in plaintext in your database.  Instead, they should be salted and hashed, then stored.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords for some good reading on this subject.  PHP has built-in functions for this - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php.

Comment: Or possibly [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206281/are-there-best-practice-standards-for-username-password) is a better fit. There's a ton of questions on password hashing here; a search should give you plenty.

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php.  Argon2 is supported in PHP 7.2 and up.